# can't assign value to home, how to assign value?

Tags: rust, enums

```rust
struct Ipv4{
    addres: String
}

struct Ipv6{
    addres: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum IPAddrKind{
    V4(Ipv4),
    V6(Ipv6)
}

fn main(){
    let home = IPAddrKind::V4(String::from("127.0.0.1"));

    println!("your ip : {:?}",home)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IPAddrKind::V4` holds a `struct Ipv4`. When you want to instantiate a `IPAddrKind::V4`, you also need to instantiate the `struct`.

```
let home = IPAddrKind::V4(Ipv4 {
  addres: String::from("127.0.0.1"),
});
```

---

Also, don't forget to add the `Debug` trait to `Ipv4` and `Ipv6`.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Ipv4 {
    addres: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Ipv6 {
    addres: String,
}
```

Comment: What exactly is ipv6 for?